# Mocking OmniAuth authentication in feature test. ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant Auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, spotify

I'm currently trying to integrate the Spotify web API into my Ruby on Rails app. Currently I am trying to use Capybara to guide my feature test through the login procedure. My test currently looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'visiting homepage' do
  it 'Allows the user to log on with Spotify' do
    visit('/')
    click_on('Sign in with Spotify')
    # expect(page).to have_content("Type in an artist, genre or mood and we'll do the rest")
  end
end
```

Realizing that I needed to mock the authentication flow of omniauth, I followed the advice of this tutorial (https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing), which suggested that I add `OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true` to my test, so that "all requests to OmniAuth will be short circuited to use the mock authentication hash as described below. A request to /auth/provider will redirect immediately to /auth/provider/callback." So I put that line in `rails_helper.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:spotify] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
  :provider => 'spotify',
  :uid => '123545'
})
```

Then, I added the redirect route to the settings on the Spotify Web API applications dashboard, as well as included the below in `config/routes.rb`

```
  get '/auth/spotify/callback'
```

However, after having done all this, I get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) visiting homepage Allows the user to log on with Spotify
     Failure/Error: click_on('Sign in with Spotify')

     ActionController::RoutingError:
       uninitialized constant Auth
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/omniauth-1.8.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:415:in `call_app!'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/omniauth-1.8.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:302:in `mock_callback_call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/omniauth-1.8.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:270:in `mock_call!'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/omniauth-1.8.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:185:in `call!'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/omniauth-1.8.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/omniauth-1.8.1/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:63:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:68:in `block in call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `each'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `call'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-test-1.0.0/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:29:in `request'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-test-1.0.0/lib/rack/test.rb:259:in `process_request'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-test-1.0.0/lib/rack/test.rb:129:in `custom_request'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rack-test-1.0.0/lib/rack/test.rb:58:in `get'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:69:in `process'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:44:in `block in process_and_follow_redirects'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:43:in `times'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:43:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:37:in `follow'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/node.rb:60:in `click'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:143:in `block in click'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:143:in `click'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:25:in `click_link_or_button'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:808:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/visiting_homepage_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # NameError:
     #   uninitialized constant Auth
     #   /Users/lw9905/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/omniauth-1.8.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:415:in `call_app!'

Finished in 0.21256 seconds (files took 5.88 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/visiting_homepage_spec.rb:4 # visiting homepage Allows the user to log on with Spotify
```

I've tried to read and understand the code in omniauth's `strategy.rb`, however, I can't find the undefined `Auth` variable the error is mentions.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding a redirect route to `config/routes.rb` - that is handled automatically by the Omniauth test mode.

Comment: You defiantly don't want a redirect there test mode or not! The callback URL should be where your application takes the incoming request from the auth provider and uses it the data provided to either authenticate an existing user or create a new user. If you redirect there the entire oauth process is pointless since the data from the request body is lost.

Comment: Ok thanks! I've removed the redirect and will deal with just the callback for now. 
I'm still getting the same `ActionController::RoutingError:uninitialized constant Auth` though